# MS Access UPDATE query is adding new rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, ms-access-2010

I'm stumped as to why this is happening. This is my UPDATE query in MS ACCESS:

```
UPDATE TempMyTable AS b
RIGHT JOIN MyTable AS a ON (a.[ID] = b.[ID])
AND (a.T3 = b.T3) AND (a.T2 = b.T2) AND (a.T1 = b.T1)
SET b.T1 = a.T1, b.T2 = a.T2, b.T3 = a.T3
WHERE (((b.ID) Is Null));
```

I'm checking for changes in the T1, T2 and T3 columns. If there's a change, update the columns in the TempMyTable rows.
However what is happening is that new rows are added with empty values in all fields except the values for T1, T2 and T3.

EDIT: solution, use INNER JOIN and check if columns DO NOT match with the '<>' operator.

```
UPDATE TempMyTable AS b
INNER JOIN MyTable AS a
ON ((a.T1 <> b.T1) OR (a.T2 <> b.T2) OR (a.T3 <> b.T3))
AND (a.[ID] = b.[ID])
SET b.T1 = a.T1, b.T2 = a.T2, b.T3 = a.T3;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Nothing is happening to these tables apart from me testing the UPDATE query on them

Comment: @Tim This is not true for MS Access. Updates with outer joins _can_  and _will_ create new records on unmatched records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `RIGHT JOIN`, which will include rows where nothing exists in `MyTable`. These rows are being updated (an `UPDATE` query in Microsoft Access always affects rows of both tables when using joins even if you're only using `Set` on columns in one table), thus creating new rows.

Change the join to an `INNER JOIN`:

```
UPDATE TempMyTable AS b
INNER JOIN MyTable AS a ON (a.[ID] = b.[ID])
AND (a.T3 = b.T3) AND (a.T2 = b.T2) AND (a.T1 = b.T1)
SET b.T1 = a.T1, b.T2 = a.T2, b.T3 = a.T3
WHERE (((b.ID) Is Null));
```

Note, however, that this query does nothing, since you're checking `WHERE (((b.ID) Is Null));`, and you're joining on `b.ID`. That means Access will be unable to return rows under any circumstance. You will likely want to remove that `WHERE` clause.

In the end, OP was looking for differences with matched IDs, thus the following query was used:

```
UPDATE TempMyTable AS b
INNER JOIN MyTable AS a
ON ((a.T1 <> b.T1) OR (a.T2 <> b.T2) OR (a.T3 <> b.T3))
AND (a.[ID] = b.[ID])
SET b.T1 = a.T1, b.T2 = a.T2, b.T3 = a.T3;
```

Comment: Very strange; I have never used Access before by the way.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Can you edit your post with the query I have edited in my post? You put me on the right track with INNER JOIN, will mark your post as answer when you've done so